# Increment/decrement the value of a field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting a wrong output when i alert this, it shows '01'

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidNavigation" name="hidNavigation" value="0" />

alert($("#hidNavigation").val($("#hidNavigation").val() + 1));
```

I am a newbie using jquery, please help me how to increment/decrement values in jquery.

Thanks,
Nash

Comment: You are concatenated the values...hence you are getting 0 + 1 = 01

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
alert($("#hidNavigation").val(parseInt($("#hidNavigation").val()) + 1));
```

Comment: isn't there a more convenient way?

Comment: @jessehattabaugh, I don't understand what do you mean by *more convenient*.

Comment: something like $('#el').val++

Comment: While the answer is correct and should work, don't forget to include the radix param, so `parseInt($("#hidNavigation").val(),10)`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I completely understand what he means by more convenient - with the radix thrown in it's a terribly ugly way to perform one of the most basic possible processing instructions

Comment: If you wish to use jQuery, combine it with the native 'value' getter: `$("#hidNavigation").get(0).value++`

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#hidNavigation").get(0).value++
```

Simply reposted from comment to @DarinDimitrov answer ... credits to @**northamerican**

Comment: Interesting occasion where Javascript seems more simple than jQuery.