# Tab index for dynamically added elements

Tags: html, jsp, tabindex, dynamically-generated, textbox

I have a jsp page with three text boxes and a ADD button beside it. Now I have to set the `tabindex` for the dynamically added elements. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[As you may have figured out by now, posting code allows someone else to give a more definite answer. Without an example to work from, I can only imagine what your code and environment is...from ASP.NET MVC3 + jQuery]

[I used the information from this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366648/increment-decrement-the-value-of-a-field-using-jquery) and modified a lit bit.]

I use jQuery to modify the tabindex value. I have multiple forms that are dynamically added by jQuery. The forms use div and style="display: table" to organize the text fields into columns.

[The relevant CSS styles]

```
.tb-table
{
    display: table;
}

.tb-row
{
    display: table-row;
}

.tb-cell
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[A chunk of my ASP.NET MVC3 Razor cshtml that produces html for the browser--should be readable]

```
<div class="tb-table">
    <div id="namerow1" class="tb-row">
        <div class="tb-label tb-cell" id="l_firstname1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname1)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-field tb-cell" id="firstname1">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstname1, new { tabindex = "1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname1)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-label tb-cell" id="l_firstname2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname2)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-field tb-cell" id="firstname2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstname2, new { tabindex = "2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname2)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="namerow2" class="tb-row">
        <div class="tb-label tb-cell">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname1)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-field tb-cell">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastname1, new { tabindex = "1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname1)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-label tb-cell">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname2)
        </div>
        <div class="tb-field tb-cell">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastname2, new { tabindex = "2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname2)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use tabindex for all values in a column; not just a unique order. For the browsers I tested in, when there are multiple text fields with the same tabindex, the text field encountered first in the html code will be selected first by tab-navigation.

Therefore, for each form that I have, I use a tab value from 0-9 to group them. Once I have the tab order for an individual form working the way I want, I use the following jQuery to INCREMENT the tabindex value by 10 (or 20, or 30, or 40) for each form that I dynamically add. the first decimal, 0-9, organizes the tabs within that form, and incrementing the factors of 10 keeps the subsequent form tabs following along.

```
$('.createtab-form [tabindex]').each(function () {$(this).attr('tabindex', parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'))+10)})
```

This is my first attempt at this myself--I'm sure someone else will have a better method. Let me know what you think.